# Can't get Foursquare to push live checkins to my URL using the venue push API

Tags: foursquare

I'm the manager of a venue and I'm trying to get checkins live using the Venue Push API. I have setup two Foursquare apps, one using my personal account and one using venue management account (as far as I understand, these are two seperate accounts because I can switch between them when I'm on foursquare.com).

When I *send test push* using the *push console* on the Foursquare developer panel from https://foursquare.com/developers/app/.../push I get a test notification to the URL that I specified, but no matter what, I haven't been able to receive checkins live.

The account is verified and I'm the manager of the venue, yet I still can't get live checkins.

Is there something I'm missing? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (or a venue manager) still needs to authorize your app to send pushes. From the docs:

> It's important to stress that in order for your app to see pushes for
>   a venue, at least one of this venue's managers must have authorized
>   use of your app, otherwise you may see “Your app can't see pushes from
>   that venue” errors.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Comment: I don't understand (not what you are sating, but how to do that). I'm the owner and manager of the venue, and I created the app (which is nothing more than a PHP script that receives FS pushes on my web server), and I can't find any way to authorize the use of the app. The only app related stuff I can find on my _user_ account is the _connected apps_ link, which only lists FS developer documentation.

Comment: Just being an owner of a venue and creating an API key doesn't mean pushes will be sent to it. You need to register for pushes (which you have) then you need a venue manager (yourself) to authorize the app. The guide on connecting explains how to generate an oauth token https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth. You can use a tool like Postman to streamline this process.

Comment: Finally found out how to authorize the app, which was done by generating an oauth token, thank you for the direction.